# jquery event delegation on/off not working in ie or firefox but works in chrome

Tags: jquery

```
  $( ' #topCurveSpinner, #rightCurveSpinner, #bottomCurveSpinner, #leftCurveSpinner').spinner({
    min: 0,
    max: 3,
    step: 1,
    spin: function(event, ui) {
      var side = $(this).data('side');
      $('#builtinCurves').empty();
        GPG.units.shape.c.builtin.top = ui.value;
        for(var i = 0; i < GPG.units.shape.c.builtin.top; i++){
          $('#builtinCurves').append(
            "<label class='builtin" + i + "'(for='builtin" + i +"') style='display:block;' > builtin curve " + (i + 1) +
              "<input class='builtinAdds builtin" + i + "' id='builtin" + i + "'type='radio', name='curveControl', value='" + i + "'></label>" + 
              "<div class='pntCtrlbuiltin builtin" + i + "' id='builtin" + i + "points' style='display:none; padding-left:10px;'>" +
                "<label class='builtin" + i + "' style='display:block;' >anchor 1" +
                  "<input class='builtin" + i + "' id='ap1builtinT'" + i + " type= 'radio' name= 'builtinpt" + i + "'></label>" +
                "<label class='builtin" + i + "' style='display:block;' >control 1" +
                  "<input class='builtin" + i + "' id='cp1builtinT'" + i + " type= 'radio' name= 'builtinpt" + i + "'></label>" +
                "<label class='builtin" + i + "' style='display:block;' >control 2" +
                  "<input class='builtin" + i + "' id='cp2builtinT'" + i + " type= 'radio' name= 'builtinpt" + i + "'></label>" +
                "<label class='builtin" + i + "' style='display:block;' >anchor 2" +
                  "<input class='builtin" + i + "' id='ap2builtinT'" + i + " type= 'radio' name= 'builtinpt" + i + "'></label>" +              
              "</div>"
            );
        }

      $('.builtinAdds').off('change.builtinAdds').on('change.builtinAdds', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $('.pntCtrlbuiltin').hide();
        $('.pntCtrlCustom').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'points').toggle();
        console.log('toggle');
      });
    }
});
```

The console.log('toggle'); will not work in ie or firefox but works in chrome.
Does anyone know why? The event 'change' is supposed to work in all. 
jquery version = 2.2, chrome version = 51, ie version = edge, firefox version = 46

Comment: A typo of adding a space at the first list of selectors appears to be stopping ie and firefox. Apparently chrome was able to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

A typo of adding a space at the first list of selectors appears to be stopping ie and firefox. Apparently chrome was able to handle it.